# Twitter plugin to display tweets from a specific user

Tags: wordpress, plugins, twitter

Twitter have retired their API v1 a few days ago.

So, does anybody know about any plugin which would allow you to display tweets from a specific user, and of course support Twitter API v1.1?

Comment: @tim Plugin to show tweets on your site

Comment: I mean what platform. Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/latest-tweets-widget/

Comment: Thanks, happy to see it was developed by you.